# A question about projective modules

Tags: homological-algebra

These is an equivalent relation about projective modules.
P is projective , 
(1)P is a direct summand of free module
(2)If P is a quotient of the R-module M, then P is isomorphic to direct summand of M.

I am confused here, what does it mean that P is a quotient of the R-module M, the quotient module of M? Am I right with here?

Answer (score 2):

This means that if $\,P\cong M/N\,$ , then $\,P\,$ is isomorphic to a direct summand of o $\,M\,$ , or what is the same: if we have a short exact sequence

$$0\longrightarrow N\longrightarrow M\stackrel{\pi}\longrightarrow P\longrightarrow 0$$

then the sequence splits...which follows directly from the definition of projective, since then we can find a homom. $\,f:P\to M\,$ s.t. $\,\pi\circ f=Id_P\,$ .

Comment: Here the sequence spilits, that means $M=P\otimes N$, so M is a direct summand, but I can not see clearly how P is a direct summand

Comment: No @user53800 , in $\,M=P\times N\,$ , it is $\,P\,$ which is a direct summand...

Comment: oh I see, P is a direct summand as a component, is that right? I think I　ｔｈｉｎｋ　ｉｔ　ｉｎ　ａ　ｗｒｏｎｇ　ｗａｙ

Comment: Indeed @user53800, though perhaps it is more comment the name of "factor" or "direct, free, whatever factor"

Comment: Thanks so much, this has confused me for a long time, because I always get wrong result by using that, :)

Comment: Anytime, @user53800 . You could always use some algebra book or the net as consultations sources, as indeed some of this stuff may be confusing.